# DevExpress grid not allowing null entry

Tags: null, grid, devexpress

I have a Devexpress grid being populated by a datatable.  If a cell in the datatable was null to begin with,  there is no problem.  But if the cell had a value and I try to change it to blank (null), then it tells me: "Input string was not in a correct format".  How can I allow this?  Is there a grid property I have to set somewhere?

Edit: SO I figured out the issue is that some columns I added are of the DataType: System.Decimal, which does not allow for empty strings.  Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're entering an empty string which isn't the same as a null value.  To enter a null into a cell in an XtraGrid you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that the people using the software aren't going to know that.  Is there a variation of the decimal datatype for a datacolumn that will allow for an empty string?